# How to avoid "video refresh" using ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, html5-video

I have created a basic chat application with text,image and video uploading option in php(codeigniter) using ajax and i am fetching the chat data every 2 seconds via  ajax in json format.

Problem is only with video "when i clicks on play video, it will play only for 2 seconds, after 2 second video is also getting reload(refreshed)". But I don't want video to be reload.

This problem i will solve by removing below code

```
setInterval(function(){get_chat_data()}, 2000)
```

But i don't want to remove this code. So here is my script and php code

```
function get_chat_data(refresh)
  { 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
      data:{ get_data: 1, chat_id: $("#chat_id").val()},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>mychat_session/get_chat_data', 
      success:function(data){
        $("#mgs_dynamic_block").html(data);  
        }, 
      });  
 }
 setInterval(function(){get_chat_data()}, 2000)
```

And here is some part of my php code

```
$get_chat_data = $this->Chat_modelM->get_chat_data();
 foreach ($get_chat_data as $chat_data) 
 {
     $message = $chat_data['chat_message']; 
     $type = $chat_data['type'];
     if($type=='video'){
     $message = base_url('uploads/chat_uploads/').$message;
     $json_all_data[] ='<video controls><source src="'.$message.'" type="video/mp4"> 
                        </video> <hr> ';
     }elseif($type=='image'){
       $message = base_url('uploads/chat_uploads/').$message;
       $json_all_data[] ='<a href="'.$message.'" target="_blank" style="display: block;">Open File</a> <hr> ';
     }else{
       $json_all_data[] ='<p class="mgs_message">'.$message.'</p><hr> '; 
     }

     if(empty($json_all_data)) {
        echo json_encode('<p class="no_mgs">No messages to display.</p>'); 
     }else{
       echo json_encode($json_all_data); 
     } 
 }
```

I expect video not be reload.

Comment: Instead of replacing the complete chat contents every 2 sec, just append any new messages to content.

Comment: I tried this, but video is getting reloaded

Comment: Show us that code instead. If you append data, it shouldn't affect the already existing video.